# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT + IN() = missing data :-(

Tags: sql, mysql, group-concat

Example:

Table: box

```
boxID  color
 01     red
 02     blue
 03     green
```

Table: boxHas

```
boxID  has
 01     apple
 01     pear
 01     grapes
 01     banana
 02     lime
 02     apple
 02     pear
 03     chihuahua
 03     nachos
 03     baby crocodile
```

I want to query on the contents of each box, and return a table with each ID, color, and a column that concatenates the contents of each box, so I use:

`SELECT box.boxID, box.color,`
`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT boxHas.has SEPARATOR ", ") AS contents`
`FROM box`
`LEFT JOIN boxHas ON box.boxID=boxHas.boxID`
`WHERE boxHas.has IN ('apple','pear')`
`GROUP BY box.boxID`
`ORDER BY box.boxID`

and I get the following table of results:

```
boxID  color  contents
 01     red    apple, pear
 02     blue   apple, pear
```

**My question to you is:** why isn't it listing ALL the `has` values in the `contents` column? Why is my `WHERE` statement also cropping my `GROUP_CONCAT`?

The table I thought I was going to get is:

```
boxID  color  contents
 01     red    apple, banana, grapes, pear
 02     blue   apple, lime, pear
```

Although I want to limit my `boxID` results based upon the `WHERE` statement, I do **not** want to limit the `contents` field for valid boxes. :-/

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use HAVING clause instead of WHERE:

```
SELECT box.boxID
     , box.color
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT boxHas.has SEPARATOR ", ") AS contents
  FROM box
  LEFT JOIN boxHas 
    ON box.boxID=boxHas.boxID
 GROUP BY box.boxID
HAVING SUM(boxHas.has IN ('apple','pear')) >= 2
 ORDER BY box.boxID
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Can -HAVING- be used with -WHERE- in the same query?

Comment: yeah they can be used at the same time, just keep in mind that WHERE is the first filter for each row, and HAVING is the second filter which acts on your aggregated(grouped) data

Comment: Thank you again. It was the final piece missing in a massive custom query! :-)